# Show search results from api call

Tags: javascript, json, api

I'm trying to make two calls to a API. First call is when the page loads, to show the ten tv shows with the highest rating from the API. That works OK right now. 
The problem now is when the search results should be displayed on the page. I want the div with id app to get updated and show the search results from what the user wrote in the input field.

I'm having trouble with the Javascript parts, that's for sure. Please help :) 
The second API call is not working correctly, I was trying to do it the same way as the first one that worked.

```
// show the shows with highest ranking
fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/shows')
    .then(blob => blob.json())
    .then(json => {
        const topTenShows = json
        .filter(show => show.rating.average) 
        .sort((a, b) => a.rating.average > b.rating.average ? -1 : 1) 
        .slice(0, 9) // tar element 0-9 i arrayen

    return topTenShows
  })
  .then(shows => {
    const app = document.getElementById('app')

    app.innerHTML = shows.map(show => `
      <div class="col-sm movie-content">
        <img src="${show.image.medium}">
        <div class="movie-info">
          <h5>${show.name}</h5>
          <span>Rating: ${show.rating.average}</span>
          <br />
          <span>Rating: ${show.genres}</span>
        </div>
      </div>

    `).join()
  })

// show the search results
function searchTvAmaze ({ target }) {
    fetch(`https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${target.value}`)
        .then(blob => blob.json())
        .then(shows => {
            const app = document.getElementById('app')

        app.innerHTML = shows.map(show => `
          <div class="col-sm movie-content">
            <img src="${show.image.medium}">
            <div class="movie-info">
              <h5>${show.name}</h5>
              <span>Rating: ${show.rating.average}</span>
              <br />
              <span>Rating: ${show.genres}</span>
            </div>
          </div>

        `).join()
      })
  }

  const inputSearchField = document.querySelector('.inputSearchField')
  inputSearchField.addEventListener('keydown', searchTvAmaze)
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-10 main-content">
    <div class="search">
        <input class="inputField inputSearchField" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    </div>  
    <div class="container">

        <div id="app" class="row">

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, by chance, you're serving your page over `https`, you won't be able to get responses from a `fetch` to an `http` endpoint. So, change the second `fetch`'s protocol to `https` instead of `http`.

The API response is structured something like this:

```
[
  { score: 20, show: {
    language: "English",
    // other properties
  }},
  // other found items
]
```

When you do

```
app.innerHTML = shows.map(show =>
```

`show` references the object with a `score` and a `show` property - it *doesn't* reference the `show` property itself. So, change to:

```
app.innerHTML = shows.map(({ show }) =>
```

to destructure the argument.

The other problem is that the `image` property of the found shows is not always there - sometimes, it's `null`. Change the `image` HTML line to something like

```
${show.image ? `<img src="${show.image.medium}">` : ''}
```

Sometimes, other properties aren't in the results either - you'll have to make the appropriate tests.

Here's an example of a mostly working version:

```js
// show the shows with highest ranking
fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/shows')
    .then(blob => blob.json())
    .then(json => {
        const topTenShows = json
        .filter(show => show.rating.average) 
        .sort((a, b) => a.rating.average > b.rating.average ? -1 : 1) 
        .slice(0, 9) // tar element 0-9 i arrayen

    return topTenShows
  })
  .then(shows => {
    const app = document.getElementById('app')

    app.innerHTML = shows.map(show => `
      <div class="col-sm movie-content">
        <img src="${show.image.medium}">
        <div class="movie-info">
          <h5>${show.name}</h5>
          <span>Rating: ${show.rating.average}</span>
          <br />
          <span>Rating: ${show.genres}</span>
        </div>
      </div>

    `).join()
  })

// show the search results
function searchTvAmaze ({ target }) {
    fetch(`https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${target.value}`)
        .then(blob => blob.json())
        .then(shows => {
            const app = document.getElementById('app')
        app.innerHTML = shows.map(({ show }) => `
          <div class="col-sm movie-content">
            ${show.image ? `<img src="${show.image.medium}">` : ''}
            <div class="movie-info">
              <h5>${show.name}</h5>
              <span>Rating: ${show.rating.average}</span>
              <br />
              <span>Rating: ${show.genres}</span>
            </div>
          </div>

        `).join();
      })
  }

  const inputSearchField = document.querySelector('.inputSearchField')
  inputSearchField.addEventListener('keydown', searchTvAmaze)
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-10 main-content">
  <div class="search">
    <input class="inputField inputSearchField" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
  </div>
  <div class="container">

    <div id="app" class="row">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked :D I'm so glad! It's so hard for me to understand Javascript. I will look more at your solution to understand it!! 
But one more question, in the browser when I look at the results, the backtick is showing, can i get rid of it somehow? :)

Comment: I'm not seeing the backtick when running the snippet, do you have an example input where you're seeing it?

Comment: It is there right from the start. When I go in to the page I see the backticks between the results. And when I write something in the input field as well.

Comment: Your page must be different from the snippet - I don't see any backticks when I run the snippet.